# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using node & Selenium WebDriver for automated testing. I am getting the following warning in my logs:

```
(node:22197) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: unexpected variable use.
```

From debugging I have found that the following line is giving this error:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser('firefox')
            .usingServer('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub')
            .build();
```

Here is the complete script:

```js
var pool = require('../../connection');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;   

module.exports = function(req, res) {

 pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM testcase_data WHERE testcase_data_id=?', [req.params.id], function(err, rows, fields) {
   var row = rows[0];
   var testdata = JSON.parse(row.json_data);
 
   var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .forBrowser('firefox')
      .usingServer('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub')
      .build();
  });
 });
};
```

How can I get rid of this error and what is wrong I am doing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something is returning a promise, and you're not handling it. Later versions of Node require you to actually handle promises, and not let them fail silently,

Comment: Try adding a handler that logs the stack trace of the exception

Comment: can you pleases let me know how can I log stack trace I am new to this

Comment: any comment on this?